# Keeping prev/next arrows visible with fancybox 1.2.6

Tags: jquery, navigation, fancybox, visible

How do I keep the prev/next arrows visible at all times using fancybox 1.2.6?

Comment: wow, not really considering to upgrade at least to v1.3.4 ?

Comment: i cant get v2.+ or v3 to work in a legacy document, so I am trying to make it work with the existing version.

Answer (score 5):

To show the navigation arrows permanently, add this CSS (inline) declaration AFTER you loaded the fancybox css file :

For fancybox **v1.2.6**

```
span#fancy_left_ico {
   left: 20px; 
} 
span#fancy_right_ico {
   right: 20px;
}
```

For **v1.3.4**

```
#fancybox-left-ico { 
   left: 20px; 
}
#fancybox-right-ico {  
   right: 20px;  
   left: auto; 
}
```

For **v2.1.3+**

```
.fancybox-nav span {
   visibility: visible;
}​
```

Comment: @AdaBell'hMonTrésor : what do you mean? there is a solution for each version, make sure you are using the right one. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/tdRc5/