# Fancybox prev/next/close buttons 'flash' when next slide is loaded

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

When you navigation through slides in a fancybox gallery, the close, previous and next buttons 'flash' when you click the previous or next arrows to load in the next slide. So they disappear and reappear in a split second. I don't see any reason why this should happen as all of the buttons are outside of the wrapper than contains the content.

Is there a way to keep them always visible with no jump/flash?

Thanks,
Steve

Note: Theres a lot of posts about the buttons not being visible until hovering over the gallery - I don't meant that! ;)

Comment: Do you mean like on fancybox examples page: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples  ?

Comment: Its hard to see on the examples because of the animation type but yes, when you click next or previous the arrows disappear and reappear.

Comment: @user1406440 : you could try making the nav arrows visible all the time http://stackoverflow.com/a/14144320/1055987

Comment: Thanks for the reply, setting visible doesn't work though. They do display without needing to hover over the fancybox - but when you click an arrow and the slides change both arrows disappear and then reappear a second later. Its almost like they're reloaded for each slide?